# How to create an AsyncTask to eliminate NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

My android app works on emulator but in phone it shows `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. From search I came to know that it can be cleared using `AsyncTask`. Can any body help me to create an `AsyncTask` which calls httppost on button click  and give back the response to `onCreate`?

Comment: It occurs on Android 3.0 and above.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/940096

Answer (score 0):

I did it and here is the code

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
  String response = "";
  for (String url : urls) {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
      String s = "";
      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        response += s;
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return response;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  textView.setText(result);
}
```

}